# spontaneous hard disk password

Tags: raid, hard-drive, sas

I had an HP proliant server go down recently.  All of the sudden the sas controller (e200i) would not see any of the physical disks.  New disks were detected just fine.  I thought it was odd that all 6 disks would go down at one time so sent them to a data recovery firm to find out what happened.  I'm being told that, somehow, all of the disks were spontaneously password protected.  These are Hitachi 2.5" drives and I guess this is something of a known issue.  The company has worked for a while to try and recover them, with no luck.  Has anyone had experience with this?  Any recommendations for how to recover the drives or a company that might have the expertise to do so?

Comment: "I guess this is something of a known issue" to who? Hitachi? If so, contact them?

Comment: Are you sure that the people are correct, because this sounds like a lot of old... uh how can I put this...

Answer (score 1):

The E200i doesn't support, even with the latest firmware, self-encrypting disk functionality - in fact there's no option within the management tools or APIs to handle encrypting disks, even if the disks themselves were these types - and I doubt they are because they're a specialist part that cost more and you'd only order them if you know you could manage that additonal functionality.

Sorry but I'm a HP and storage geek and I call bullshit on their excuse.

Answer (score 0):

Strange how the "data recovery firm" can't recover the data. As far as I know, the data is not encrypted on the drive, so they should be able to recover it. Call up a few other firms and ask them if they can extract data from password locked drives.